# How to change mime type of a mp3 file using ffmpeg using php

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I want to convert a mp3 file using `ffmpeg`. My current mp3 file is in `audio/x-mpeg` I want to convert it into `audio/mpeg`. This only changes the file extension without affecting the mime type.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3  -metadata:s:2 mime-type="audio/mpeg" output.mp3
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f audio/mpeg output.mp3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect the result to be. Mime types are uasually configured as part of your web server and not part of the file being served.

Comment: My IIS server has included the mime type of audio/mpeg. I just need to change the mime type of my file so that it can play in jw player. My file mime type is audio/x-mpeg and i need to convert it in audio/mpeg.Thanks

Comment: @john I belive we are confused by your use of the word mime types. What you really mean is that you want to convert the file from x-mpeg to normal mpeg, and are verifying that it works through the mime types? In that case, your command would return an error? Could you paste it here?